# Qual o melhor jeito de gerar erros personalizados

Tags: javascript, node.js

Por exemplo, o usuário digita um valor inválido, e eu quero gerar um erro. Seria usando `throw new Error("Você digitou um valor inválido")` e tratando com `try/catch` como em Java? Ou tem um jeito melhor para fazer isso com Nodejs?

Comment: `throw` é usado para erros internos e "mais graves" que um erro do utilizador. Um alert simplesmente já faz o efeito de mostrar que houve algo errado. Mas se explicares melhor o que o utilizador está a fazer, o que é input valido e errado posso ser mais especifico.

Answer (score 1):

Não existe "melhor jeito", mas sim linhas gerais.

Um `alert()` permite enviar uma janela de erro para o usuário, mas tem o problema de bloquear o navegador inteiro no processo - podendo prejudicar a experiência dele.
Para ajudar o seu usuário, você pode:

- Exibir uma tooltip no seu campo de input avisando o usuário que o valor informado é inválido;
- Utilizar as ferramentas padrão a seu favor: ao montar um formulário dentro de uma tag `<form>`, o navegador te ajuda a validar o formulário. Campos de tipo `email`, `number`, ou com atributos como `required` e `maxlength` bloqueiam o `<submit>` do formulário automaticamente até que todos os dados estejam de acordo com o solicitado.
- Não deixe a validação do formulário apenas no front-end, faça a verificação dos tipos desejados no back-end e retorne um erro com código 500 (Internal Server Error) para quando um input inválido for identificado.

Por exemplo, para enviar um erro usando o Express:

```
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) { 
  console.error(err.stack); 
  res.status(500).send('Something broke!');
});
```

Outra opção: você pode indicar na resposta de erro quais campos estão inválidos:

```
 res.status(500).send( JSON.stringify( { invalidFields: ['nome','endereço'] } ));
```

E no seu front-end exibir uma tarja com as informações:
"Os seguintes campos estão com formatação inválida: nome, endereço"